# Problems with addClass in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, addclass

I'm having problems with selectors in jQuery. Or (what I don't think) with my jQuery code.

Let me say about my problem.
I have a Rails project and a I want to insert in my menu, the class "active" if the current page is same at the menu.

For example:

Current page: Posts
My menu:

- Pages (class: none)
- Users (class: none)
- Posts (class: "active")
- Blablabla ...

My HTML/Rails/jQuery code (if you're a Rails developer, this is my layout):

Menu:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li id="dashboard"><%= link_to "Dashboard", admin_index_path %></li>
  <li id="notes"><%= link_to "Notes", admin_notes_path %>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">List notes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Add note</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="projects"><a href="#">Projects</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">List projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Add project</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="users"><a href="#">Users</a></li>
</ul>
```

Script:

```
<script>
 $("#hld #wrapper #header #nav li").addClass(function() {
   var addedClass;

   if ($(this).attr('id') === "<%= content_for(:title).downcase %>") {
    return "active";
   }

   return addedClass;
 });
</script>

<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.img.preload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.filestyle.mini.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.wysiwyg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.date_input.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/facebox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.visualize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.visualize.tooltip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.select_skin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/ajaxupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.pngfix.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/custom.js"></script>
```

Look for the script and there'll have my script in jQuery of course.
So, what's the problem?

Thanks for helping, I tried to be clear.
Lucas Moreira.

Comment: Can you show us the actual generated page so we can see the real javascript, not the Rails page before processing.  For example, I have no idea what this actually turns into: `"<%= content_for(:title).downcase %>"`.

Comment: Also, is there any reason you're using: `#hld #wrapper #header #nav li` instead of just `#nav li` as the selector.  Ids are unique in the page so you don't need multiple ids in the selector to target one.

Comment: I did what you said (changing '#hld #wrapper #header #nav li' to '#nav li') and still not working.

Comment: Also, when a I access the site e view the source-code: '<script>
   $("#nav li").addClass(function() {
     var addedClass;
  
     if ($(this).attr('id') === "dashboard") {
      return "active";
     }
 
  return addedClass;
   });
 </script>'

Comment: As you can see from this jsFiddle, the concept works if you code is doing what you're trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/jwg3S/.  Without seeing your functioning web page, I'm not sure we can really tell you more about what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jfriend00 pointed out, your selector is unnesscesarily long.  `'#nav li'` will suffice.
Better yet, since you are only (presumably) looking for a direct child of #nav use `'#nav > li'`.

Also (someone please correct me if I'm wrong) but I think your script should go below where you load the external scripts.  Trying to use JQuery before its loaded may cause problems ;-)

Comment: Oh. My. God. hahaha
The problemas was that: I was running the code before load the jQuery.

Thanks for all, again!